# VAR interpretation

Tags: risk-management, value-at-risk

I definitely struggle to understand the following interpretation of VAR (value at risk) provided by Jorion

$$VAR(c)=E[X]−Q(X,c)$$

where $X$ is a random variable, $E[X]$ its expected value, $Q(X,c)$ the quantile of its distribution such that the associated probability is c.

Isn't VAR the quantile itself? Why should it be viewed as a deviation from the mean?

Comment: Two reasons:
1) "Risk" is interpreted as deviation from what you would expect.
2) If VAR were equal to the quantile you would not need a new word for it.

Answer (score 2):

VaR is the quantile of the loss distribution but $X$ in your post no doubt denotes the the future value of the portfolio. If $E[X]=10$ (expected future value of portfolio) and the quantile $Q(X,c)=4$ for some $c$, then your VaR, that is the lost that represents the outcome at the quantile, is $$VaR(c) = E[X] - Q(X,c) = 10 - 4 = 6$$